# How do I make the equivalent of a C double pointer in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust

I started porting C code to Rust, but I'm confused about how things work in Rust. What is the equivalent of this code:

```c
typedef struct Room {
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
} Room;

void main (){
  Room **rooms;
  rooms = malloc(sizeof(Room)*8);
}
```

Comment: Uh... that C code is wrong. I guess you're missing a `*` in `sizeof(Room)`? (Which is why you should always write `(sizeof *rooms)` instead btw)

Comment: Asking "how do I get a double C pointer" is not very useful, because that's a C feature and Rust will have its own way of doing things. It can be done but will result in horrible code. Instead, ask about whatever you actually want to achieve (e.g. "how do I create a dynamic array of objects on the heap").

Comment: @trentcl thanks, your're right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the equivalent of this code

Assuming you mean "a collection of `Room`s with capacity for 8":

```
struct Room {
    x_pos: i32,
    y_pos: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let rooms: Vec<Room> = Vec::with_capacity(8);
}
```

It's exceedingly rare to call the allocator directly in Rust. Generally, you have a collection that does that for you. You also don't usually explicitly specify the item type of the collection because it can be inferred by what you put in it, but since your code doesn't use `rooms` at all, we have to inform the compiler.

As pointed out in the comments, you don't need a double pointer. This is the equivalent of a `Room *`. If you really wanted an additional level of indirection, you could add `Box`:

```
let rooms: Vec<Box<Room>> = Vec::with_capacity(8);
```

> How do I make the equivalent of a C double pointer

One of the benefits of Rust vs C is that in C, you don't know the semantics of a `foo_t **`. Who should free each of the pointers? Which pointers are mutable? You *can* create raw pointers in Rust, but even that requires specifying mutability. **This is almost never what you want**:

```
let rooms: *mut *mut Room;
```

In certain FFI cases, a C function accepts a `foo_t **` because it wants to modify a passed-in pointer. In those cases, something like this is reasonable:

```
unsafe {
    let mut room: *mut Room = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let room_ptr: *mut *mut Room = &mut room;
}
```