# What is the proper way to use a pointer to pointer in a foreign function in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a DLL that exports a bunch of C functions which I'd like to use in Rust. I have the following exported functions that are used to create a handle and delete it for the DLL API, respectively:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int create_handle(handle** ptr);
__declspec(dllexport) int close_handle(handle* h);
```

I tried implementing it in a few different manners such as this:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_int, c_float, c_void};

#[link(name = "my_dll")]
extern {
   fn create_handle(handle: *mut c_int) -> i32;
   fn close_handle(handle: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut ptr = 0 as i32;
        let ret = create_handle(&mut ptr);
        if ret != 0 {
            panic!("return code fail: {0}", ret);
        }

        let ret = close_handle(ptr);
        if ret != 0 {
            panic!("return code fail: {0}", ret);
        }
    }
}
```

Although `ptr` is assigned a value, it is not the expected one. The `close_handle` native function checks if the passed pointer matches the created one. In this code, the second `panic!` is reached.

I am very new to Rust so the pointer interoperability is not very clear to me at the moment. The native function will do the proper type casting, so should I be using the `c_void` type? Or is a `i32` with the pointer value enough?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what the types (`handle`) or functions (`create_handle` / `close_handle`) present in the code are.

Comment: Your function is declared as `(handle** ptr)`, but the Rust equivalent is `(handle: *mut c_int)`. Why do you believe that these are equivalent types?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I make the equivalent of a C double pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47878236/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Fixed the image import (it is part of a bigger program, I copied by mistake). Thanks for the info on the revision history. I dont see how to include a minimal reproducible example without the DLL. I'll check the provided link and give a follow up.

Comment: The *minimized* DLL code should likely boil down to one or two statements per function, plus another few for for the definition of `handle`, for a likely total of ~10 lines. That's easily included and the entire point of creating a [MRE].

Comment: @Shepmaster the last bit of the linked answer was what I was missing. The *mut *mut notation was not something I was familiar with, but looking at it now it makes sense. The working solution could be added as an edit marker?

Comment: If you don't think that the linked question is a duplicate, you can answer your own question below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution:

```
extern crate libc;

#[link(name = "my_dll")]
extern {
   fn create_handle(handle_ptr: *mut *mut i32) -> i32;
   fn close_handle(handle: *mut i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut handle: *mut i32 = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let handle_ptr: *mut *mut i32 = &mut handle;

        let ret = create_handle(handle_ptr);
        if ret != 0 {
            panic!("return code fail: {0}", ret);
        }

        let ret = close_handle(handle);
        if ret != 0 {
           panic!("return code fail: {0}", ret);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution was the `*mut *mut` notation to reference a `std::ptr::null_mut()`, found on [How do I make the equivalent of a C double pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47878236/155423).